# Where is wordpress redirecting wp-admin/admin/dashboard to wp-admin and how to turn it off

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, rewrite-rules

I mean when we have subdirectory install and /wp-admin/ is not referencing to directory wp-admin, but wordpress stills redirects and not just for wp-admin slug but also for admin and dashboard and maybe some more?

Where is this happening?
It is not in rewrite rules?
Is it hard coded?

I don't want this behavior and i want to turn it off, but i want clean solution, nota check url and if slug is present than do my redirect.

Edit:

When you visit `example.com/login` you're redirected to the login page, and `example.com/dashboard` redirects to the admin area. How can I disable this behaviour or change the redirect location?

I have my own login and dashboard interfaces and would like to use those instead

Comment: So you want to change where the user goes when they login from the WP Admin dashboard to somewhere else?

Comment: No, i want to know where are these endpoints settled. I defined my own endpoint for login and wp-admin, but i want to turn off theese

Comment: hmmm, so do you mean the rewrite rules? Or do you mean the functions that actually put the URLs on the page? You've not provided any outright examples so it's a little difficult to determine what you mean, there's still some ambiguity left in your question

Comment: Man, just type yourwordpress.com/dashboard and it will redirect to wp-admin. I want to know where in core files this happens, and is there filter for this, is it uses rewrites or hard code redirect, i dont get how do you dont understend my question

Comment: Ah! You mean the `/login` and `/dashboard` redirects! That clears things up :) A lot of people are unaware those exist, and there are other ways to redirect to those locations

Comment: I dont want to change core, i only want to know where are  they handled in core?

Comment: i see that, they aren't handled by rewrites, so it must have been hard coded in core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove this functionality by adding this code in a plugin or theme

`remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'wp_redirect_admin_locations', 1000 );`

This will remove all of dashboar, login, admin so if you will want some of them to still be there you will have to write your own replacement function to `wp_redirect_admin_locations` and hook it after you removed the hook to the original